# Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax for a CREATE VIEW query

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to answer this question: Create a view of all patient details (patient, ward, drugs) for all patients who are 70 years old or older, excluding ward number and number of beds.

From this schema:

```
    Patient (patientNo, patName, patAddr, DOB)
    Ward (wardNo, wardName, wardType, noOfBeds)
    Contains (patientNo, wardNo, admissionDate)
    Drug (drugNo, drugName, costPerUnit)
    Prescribed (patientNo, drugNo, unitsPerDay, startDate, finishDate)
```

The query I have written is:

```
    CREATE VIEW [Patients Over Seventy] AS
    SELECT p.*, c.admissionDate, r.drugNo, r.unitsPerDay, r.startDate, r.finishDate
    FROM Patient p, Contain c, Prescribed r
    WHERE p.patientNo=c.patientNo AND p.DOB <=1952-05-31;
```

But I keep getting the error:
"Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Patients Over Seventy] AS SELECT p.*, c.admissionDate, r.drugNo, r.unitsPerDay,' at line 1"

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Not sure about the syntax containing the `[]` characters, but try with `CREATE VIEW Patients_Over_Seventy ...` instead.

Comment: @PaulT. Just gave that a go, and the same error is still coming up sadly

Comment: Try checking the SQL query itself runs without the CREATE VIEW name AS. If not try enclosing the field names with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues.

1. Table name in the schema Contains, in the view - Contain
2. There is no condition to join Prescribed table to the other two tables
3. What is DOB data type? If it's char, the comparison should be p.DOB <='1952-05-31', if it's date, you need to use SQL CONVERT function